# Sometimes my Linux tablet screen is dark after boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, ubuntu-16.04, xorg.conf

I have installed Ubuntu on a PIPO X10 Pro tablet. It's a simple tablet running Intel x5-Z8350 with a DSI screen.

After booting, the display turns completely black. I am able to SSH into the machine, and try all sorts of commands to manipulate the display. I've been searching for a way to detect that the screen is black - and then force it to reboot again (which is a sucky solution).

I have no idea what's wrong. I can say that the device is using UEFI. In BIOS I have restored defaults.

## dmesg|grep -i vga

```
[    0.394916] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    0.394933] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.394951] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.394960] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    1.870261] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    3.018244] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    3.022697] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    3.099731] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
```

## xrandr

This shows the same, regardless if the screen is working or not.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1280, maximum 32767 x 32767
DSI1 connected 1920x1280+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1280     60.00*+
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

## Tried so far

### .xinitrc

I have put these in ~/.xinitrc

1. xset s off -dpms
2. xset s noblank
3. xset dpms force on; xset s reset
4. xset dpms 0 0 0
5. xrandr --output DSI1 --off; sleep 1; xrandr --output DSI1 --auto

### Open TTY 2..6

If I open TTY 2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2) while booting, it seems the screen stays on when X starts on TTY 1.

If I don't open TTY 2 until after X has blanked my screen, the other TTYs are also black.

When I press Caps-Lock on TTY 1, while screen is blank - the LED on my keyboard changes.

When I switch to TTY 2, the Caps-Lock button does not seem to work. It works again when I switch back to TTY 1 - but the screen is still black.

Comment: Does rebooting the tablet cause the screen to turn on? What percentage of the time does the screen start dark, do you estimate?

Comment: @music2myear It may be 50 % of the time. Now it has happened 4 times in a row. Each time after I use the `reboot` command. I can log into the console. It seems Xorg.0.log is from earlier today - I don't know why it is not updating. The screen is ON while booting. It turns off when X starts.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it, with a quirky fix.

As I explained in the question, the screen does not go dark if I switch to TTY 2 during boot.

I discovered the command chvt which basically is a script that starts TTY 2, so the solution was to run `chvt 2` (as root) before X starts.